# Error while installing any specific version of ruby through rvm in mac m1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

I am facing an issue while installing any version of ruby through rvm in Mac m1. Globally, I have installed ruby version 3.0.0 but for a project, I needed version 3.0.2 but it gives me the following error, no matter how many different versions I try to install the error is the same:

`Error running '__rvm_make -j8',`

`please read /Users/hammadahmad/.rvm/log/1692909928_ruby-2.7.4/make.log`

`There has been an error while running the make. Halting the installation.`

I have tried reinstalling RVM but still no solution. I even tried to do it when rbenv but it gives me other issues like incompatible environment bootsnap.

I tried everything but nothing worked so I'm tired of this.
I want it to work properly and by properly I want to install any version of ruby with the ruby version manager as it does on any other system, The error it is showing is not encountered to anyone else and if it does then there is no guidance about it.

Comment: Did you read the indicated log under "please read"?

Comment: Yes, I have read it, it is showing me a very long make.log file that relates to a few deprecations in OpenSSL and I don't know how to fix the issue